# PHP Cookie doesn't work

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to access a cookie I just set in an other page on the same domain, but it doesn't work. When I'm doing `echo $_COOKIE`, the array is empty on the new page, but contains the cookie on the creation page.

Here is the code in /PROC/LOGIN.PROC.PHP

```
//Set the cookie for 1 year.
setcookie("username", $username, time()+365*24*60*60);
setcookie("password", $password, time()+365*24*60*60);
```

Here's the code in /INC/HEADER.INC.PHP

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
include("pages/user.header.pages.php");
```

But when I'm trying to isset the cookie or only display the array in header.inc.php, the array is empty.

Comment: By the way, I'm working in local (localhost)

Comment: Don't store passwords in a cookie!

Comment: Run var_dump($_COOKIES) to show what values are in the $_COOKIES variable, running a print alone will not tell you the contents of the array.

Comment: Remember to use firebug on firefox to watch what the browser is doing with the cookies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the `path` value of the cookie to the root of your domain, [as per the docs](http://php.net/setcookie):

```
setcookie("username", $username, time()+365*24*60*60, '/');
```

Otherwise, it will be set to the current working directory, which is `/PROC/` for your example. So, only scripts in `/PROC/` would be able to use that cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Check out, your PHP setcookie definition is done before declare HEADs. If not, the cookie is not stored.

So take control of your cookies at the beginning of code, before sending headers or other HTML entities.

Comment: This saved me  I think this should be emphasized on the php.net "Common Pitfalls" section of the setcookie() function - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php