# PHP set cookie on own VPS doesn't work

Tags: php

Whats wrong with this code?

```
<?php
    setcookie("userid", $rowInfo["id"], time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
?>
```

It doesn't work. Im running webhosting on my own server, maybe i have to install something, i dont know.

Comment: I assume `$rowInfo["id"]` is a simple piece of text, but just to be sure what is in that variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Cookie doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677921/php-cookie-doesnt-work)

Comment: There is user's ID (read form DB). But I replaced it with some text and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MattS i added path, didn't help

Comment: How are you determining that it didn't work?